# Unable to dynamically add an element to a page using Kotlin and XML

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, frontend

this is going to be a bit longer, but I've been trying to add an element that I have defined separately to a layout. Now, I don't know in advance how many of them there are and what are my ImageView and TextView are going to be for each of them. I want to define that in the backend. I have tried several variants but none have worked.

This is my code in Kotlin:

```
private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resources.getStringArray(R.array.countries_array))
        val gridScreen = findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.grid_screen)
        for(i in 1..4){
            val gridItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.container, null)
            //val gridItem = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.container,null)
            //gridItem.id = View.generateViewId() ###this did not work
            val image1 = gridItem.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_1) 
            //these images exist in this folder by this name
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1)
            ...etc for each element

            val text = gridItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.category)
            text.text = "Text for item $i"
            print(text.text)
            gridScreen.addView(gridItem)
        }
```

This is my page layout in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="150sp"
        android:minWidth="160sp"
        android:maxWidth="160sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/grid_screen">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/container_include"
            layout="@layout/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_emptyTextView"
            android:text="No result"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.widget.GridLayout>
```

And this is my container that I want to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="150sp"
              android:layout_height="160sp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="140sp"
                android:layout_height="70sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_1"
                    android:layout_width="70sp"
                    android:layout_height="65sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_2"
                    ...same thing/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="140sp"
            android:layout_height="70sp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_3"
                ...same thing/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_4"
                ...same thing/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15sp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Cathegory"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this code, only one element is displayed in the top left corner (and that is when I add android:src to each ImageView. Let me know if you have any advice on how to fix this. It is driving me crazy. Also, if there are some things missing in the post, or some things are unnecessary, let me know to remove them. Thank you:)

Comment: Shot in the dark ... but don't you need rowspec and colspec to be set for the gridlayout?

Comment: @BitWiseByteDumb how do I implement that?

Comment: Check this out. They are using the numColumns property: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-gridview-layout-in-an-android-app-using-kotlin